# EOFException when trying to pass the object through sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to pass an object through sockets, from the server to the client, what happens is that in some PCs it works well, and in others it does not. The object is updated indefinitely, so obviously I use an infinite loop to send the object indefinitely. When trying to execute the client sends the following error:

```
java -jar PC-CheckClient.jar 192.168.1.71 -console
Successfully established connection with server PC-CHECK
Starting... It may take several seconds
jul 11, 2019 1:34:31 AM com.he.pc.view.Main <init>
GRAVE: null 
java.io.EOFException 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.he.pc.view.Main.<init>(Main.java:39)
    at com.he.pc.view.Main.main(Main.java:93)
```

This is the code sonde command the object from the server

```
private void sendData() {
        //Declarar, instanciar e inicializar
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            //Puerto 5000
            int puerto = 5000;
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(puerto);
            System.out.println("Establishing connection with the PC-CHECK client");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Successfully established connection");
            System.out.println("Starting... It may take several seconds");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            while (true) {
                //Obtencion del hardware
                this.cpuMain = this.loadCPU();
                this.ram = this.loadRAM();
                //Envio de datos al pc cliente
                oos.writeObject(this.cpuMain);
                oos.writeObject(this.ram);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if(oos != null){
                    oos.close();
                }
                if(socket != null){
                    socket.close();
                }
                if(serverSocket != null){
                    serverSocket.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here the client receives it

```
public Main(String ip) {

        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, 5000);
            System.out.println("Successfully established connection with server PC-CHECK");
            System.out.println("Starting... It may take several seconds");
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while(true){
                this.cpu = (CPU)ois.readObject();
                Utilities.clear();
                System.out.println("CPU: ");
                System.out.println(cpu.toString());

                this.ram = (RAM) ois.readObject();
                System.out.println("RAM: ");
                System.out.println(this.ram.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }finally {
            try {
                if (socket != null) {
                    socket.close();
                }
                if (ois != null) {
                    ois.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is how can I solve this error, and make sure that all computers work properly?

Thank you

Comment: The sender closed the connection. Maybe *it* got an exception?

Comment: No, the server does not show any error or exception, while the client shows the exception described above

Comment: Hard to believe. It closed the socket for some reason, and the only way out of that `while (true)` loop is an `Exception` or an `Error`. Maybe it got a `RuntimeException`?

Comment: The server does not throw an exception, the connection is not closed either, later I show what the server prints, but it does not produce any exception

Comment: The connection is *certainly* being closed by the peer. That's what `EOFException` *means*. I can only suggest you examine all your assumptions.

Comment: I note that you have `catch (Exception e){ }`. Code like this is certainly no way to assert no exception was thrown.

Comment: If I add or remove the exception block, it does not affect the problem, the client will continue throwing the same exception, and no exception is shown on the server